# making a session cookie expire in 2 years

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies

I have the below script that sets cookies and pulls values into the forms. What I am struggling with is setting the expiration date for 2 years?

```
      // Parse the URL
      function getParameterByName(name) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
      var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
      results = regex.exec(location.search);
      return results === null ? "" : 
      decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
      }

      // Give the URL parameters variable names
      var source = getParameterByName('utm_source');
      var keyword = getParameterByName('keyword');
      var medium = getParameterByName('utm_medium');
      var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign');
      var _ga = getParameterByName('_ga');
      var gclid = getParameterByName('gclid');
      var clientId = getParameterByName('clientId');

      // Set the cookies
      if(Cookies.set('utm_source') == null || Cookies.set('utm_source') == 
      "") { 
      Cookies.set('utm_source', source, { path: ''}); 
      }
      if(Cookies.set('keyword') == null || Cookies.set('keyword') == "") {
      Cookies.set('keyword', keyword, { path: '' });
      }
      if(Cookies.set('utm_medium') == null || Cookies.set('utm_medium') ==                     
      "") {
      Cookies.set('utm_medium', medium, { path: '' });
      }
      if(Cookies.set('utm_campaign') == null || Cookies.set('utm_campaign') 
      == "") {
      Cookies.set('utm_campaign', campaign, { path: '' });
      }
      if(Cookies.set('_ga') == null || Cookies.set('_ga') == "") {
      Cookies.set('_ga', _ga, { path: '' });
      }
      if(Cookies.set('gclid') == null || Cookies.set('gclid') == "") {
      Cookies.set('gclid', gclid, { path: '' });
      }
      if(Cookies.set('clientId') == null || Cookies.set('clientId') == "") {
      Cookies.set('clientId', clientId, { path: '' });
      }

      // Grab the cookie value and set the form field values
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[name=utm_source]:hidden").val(source);
      $("input[name=keyword]:hidden").val(keyword);
      $("input[name=utm_medium]:hidden").val(medium);
      $("input[name=gclid]:hidden").val(gclid);
      $("input[name=utm_campaign]:hidden").val(campaign);
      $("input[name=_ga]:hidden").val(_ga);
      $("input[name=clientId]:hidden").val (clientId);
      });
     </script>
```

Thanks - everthing above works as expected but I have having a hard time setting the cookies to expire in two years - I have tried various [expires] but to no avail.

Comment: Makes no sense using `set()` within `if()` conditionals

Comment: Doesn't that mean if cookie 'clientId' is null (doesn't exist) then set cookie clientId. And the last section "Cookies.set('clientId', clientId, { path: '' });" is name, value get from parameter and add path?

Comment: No ... that is not what it means. Use `get()` to check values

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer if anyone needed to know... I am just showing the first utm_source for the answer but they would all follow suit

```
   if(Cookies.set('utm_source') == null || Cookies.set('utm_source') == "") 
   { 
   Cookies.set('utm_source', source, { path: ''});
   var myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 24);
   document.cookie = 'utm_source' +"=" + source + ";expires=" + myDate
              + "path=/";
   }
```